# How to use Vue.prototype or global variable in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

Like the title, I want to add Axios into Vue prototype. So when I want to use it, I can use it like `this.$axios` instead of importing it every time.

**CODE:**

```js
//plugins/axios.ts

import axios from 'axios'
import router from '../router/index'

const errorHandle = (): void => {};

const instance = axios.create({
  // baseURL: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development' ? '' : ''
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
  timeout: 1000 * 12
});

instance.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'

export default instance
```

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import installElementPlus from './plugins/element'
import instance from './plugins/axios'
import router from './router'

const app = createApp(App).use(router)
installElementPlus(app)
// app.config.globalProperties.http = instance
app.config.globalProperties.$axios= instance
app.mount('#app')
```

However, there is a problem when I try to use it like this: `this.$axios`.

```sh
TS2339: Property '$axios' does not exist on type 'ComponentPublicInstance<{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, EmitsOptions, {}, {}, false, ComponentOptionsBase<{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, EmitsOptions, string, {}>>'.
```

How could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You could use `provide`/`inject` or define a global config property, which replaces `Vue.prototype` in Vue 3:

### 1. [`provide`/`inject`](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#provide-inject) (for Composition or Options API)

**Provide**

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const app = Vue.createApp(App);
app.provide('$axios', axios);  // Providing to all components during app creation
```

**Inject**

*Composition API:*

```js
const { inject } = Vue;
...
setup() {
  const $axios = inject('$axios');   // injecting in a component that wants it
  // $axios.get(...)
}
```

*Options API:*

```js
inject: ['$axios'],   // injecting in a component that wants it
```

### 2. [Global config](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#vue-prototype-replaced-by-config-globalproperties) (for Options API)

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const app = Vue.createApp(App);
app.config.globalProperties.$axios = axios;
```

*Options API:*

```
this.$axios
```

<sup>Note: This is only for the Options API.  Evan You (Vue creator) [says](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/1074#issuecomment-621427943): "*`config.globalProperties` are meant as an escape hatch for replicating the behavior of `Vue.prototype`. In `setup` functions, simply import what you need or explicitly use `provide`/`inject` to expose properties to app.*"</sup>

Comment: Option #2 worked beautifully as a substitute. Used for adding analytics tracking through an application.

Answer (score 12):

There is a way to use `globalProperties` inside a setup function. Although this might be considered an anti-patter. It would be better to use provide/inject if possible. But if there is a library that uses globalProperties and you really need to access it from setup this is how you could do it.

```html
<script setup>
    import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

    const app = getCurrentInstance()
    const progressBar = app.appContext.config.globalProperties.$Progress

    progressBar.start()
</script>
```